# How to block access of specific client and revoke his issued tokens in admin console

Tags: spring-boot, authorization, keycloak, access-token, refresh-token

I implemented Authorization Server with spring boot and keycloak using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-dependencies-server-all</artifactId>
    <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I defined a client to have **client_credentials** authorization flow in keycloak admin console. everything is ok and client can get his access_token and refresh_token.

Now, i want to be able to revoke this client issued tokens and also prevent his to get new token. how and where can i do that in keycloak admin console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Access Tokens` cannot be revoked (at least in **Keycloak**). They are designed to be short-lived and its very good practice to set their expiry time between 1 and 3 minutes.

The only thing you can do is:

- **Evict all sessions** of a particular user
- Disable/**deny access** to this particular user (so that he will not get new tokens)
- **Change keys** or regenerate secret credentials of a particular Client (so that it will not be possible to authenticate against nor will it issue new tokens)
- Use **not-before push** policy for all tokens **or disable/delete the Client** or application

More actions and details are available here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#compromised-access-and-refresh-tokens

"*Token lifetime*" and "*Revoking access*" topics are partly covered here:

- https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/
- https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/listing-authorizations/revoking-access/

Comment: Dear @bsaverino could you answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979133/how-to-do-ip-restrictation-for-clients-in-keycloak-admin-console