# How to do IP restrictation for clients in keycloak admin console

Tags: authorization, keycloak, ip-restrictions, clientcredential

I defined a client in keycloak admin console to authorize it with client_credentials flow to call server-to-server api in my application. Everything is fine, i want to apply IP restriction for that client.

Where can i define this restriction in admin console? i didn't find such configuration in keycloak documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such settings out of the box, but you could try to implement custom client authenticator. So for example allowed IP Addr could be stored in client attributes, and your authenticator implementation will challenge incoming request against specified IP addr. See "Server Development" section in Keycloak documentation. Also you can refer to keycloak github repo for implementation examples and guides. Start from

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/client/ClientIdAndSecretAuthenticator.java

Comment: Nice suggestion, though I strongly believe that IP Filtering should happen in the (reverse) proxy, WAF or security gateway.

Comment: @solveMe Thanks for you solution. Now i have another question, where and how should i set attributes for clients? i didn't find it in admin console and it's documentation.

Comment: @RasoolGhafari In admin console there is no UI for setting client attribuites, but if you dump client you can see that dump contains 'attributes' field, so you could try to use admin api for settings attribute value (i know, i know that it is not very convenient). Honestly i don't know whether this fields for internal usage or not. If so you could also consider to extend keycloak DB schema with custom IP settings entity (see howto in documentation).

Comment: because of @bsaverino suggestion, i checked zuul, but have this problem, could help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991711/spring-cloud-zuul-does-not-load-static-resources-from-spring-boot-applications

Comment: Zuul also could be a solution, but i'm also a newbie in spring-netflix environment

Comment: Same .. can't help with Zuul. Note that if you are prototyping you may have better chances with more popular tools like `nginx`. I don't say that Zuul isn't a good choice but as you are experimenting already with one (or more) technology it may be worth to keep most of the rest under control :) Eventually `Keycloak Gatekeeper` (or `Louketo Proxy`) may be more convenient to start with as it has a strong relationship with Keycloak.