# Keycloak IP address restrictions for client(end-user)

Tags: keycloak

I want to restrict client(end-user) by IP-address on Keycloak.
Way of Admin console seem to be following url, but there was no information about the client.

[How to do IP restrictation for clients in keycloak admin console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979133/how-to-do-ip-restrictation-for-clients-in-keycloak-admin-console)

Does anyone know any information?

Comment: When you say "client" here are you refering to Keycloak's concept of a client (like in the OIDC spec) or an end-user device (like a laptop or mobile phone)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to implement your own Authenticator. You can get the IP of the end user by `context.getConnection().getRemoteAddress()`.

Here is the Javadoc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/16.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/common/ClientConnection.html#getRemoteAddr--

Note that this is probably easier to do with a reverse proxy (i.e. nginx) in front of keycloak (like the linked post suggests).