# How to restrict specif ip address only to get the access token from the keycloak

Tags: client, keycloak, access-token, ip-address, custom-authentication

We want to create a custom authenticator to restrict the IP addresses such that particular applications coming with specific IP addresses can get the access token based on the provided client ID and client secret. If some other application with no restricted IP addresses tries to access, they should not be issued an access token. At present, we have created a custom authenticator by implementing keycloak authenticating interface and we have copied that custom authenticated jar file to the provider folder to the keycloak while starting keycloak this custom authenticator loads without issue. After logging into keycloak when we click on the clients flow in the authentication section we cannot see this custom authenticator whereas when we create a new flow as a basic flow we can see this basic flow of custom authenticator how can we see this custom authenticator in clients flow so that we can use it with the combination of client id and client secret flow step.

Comment: Someone already mention your question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979133/how-to-do-ip-restrictation-for-clients-in-keycloak-admin-console)